# Unable to import nvprof generated profile data

Tags: python, cuda, tensorflow, nvprof

I am trying to profile a TensorFlow based code using **nvprof**. I am using following command for this

```
nvprof  python ass2.py
```

The program runs successfully but at the end it shows following error.

```
==49791== Profiling application: python ass2.py
======== Error: Unable to import nvprof generated profile data.
```

Comment: Could you try `nvprof --profile-child-processes python ass2.py`? The profile-child-processes option is needed because your target application - python - probably executes GPU stuff in a new spawned process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason but using the full path of nvprof `/usr/bin/nvprof` solved the problem.

Comment: perhaps because you have more than one `nvprof` on your system, from different versions of CUDA, and your `PATH` environment variable is picking up the wrong one.

Answer (score 8):

use `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvprof xxx`,  maybe you have install two versions of cuda

OR 
you can add `/usr/local/cuda/bin` to `PATH` enviroment.

```
vim ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Solved my problem!